# inserting byte array into blob column

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to insert byte array into a blob column in sqlite database. I've tried with both setBinaryStream and setBytes, but I'm getting not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver exception. I'm using sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar.What jar should I use to get this work? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
 public void addDriverData(String prenume,String nume,String telefon,String email,String permis,String parola,byte[] photo) throws SQLException
    { String sql = "INSERT INTO driver(first_name,last_name,phone,email,permit,password,photo)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        stm.setString(1,prenume);
        stm.setString(2,nume);
        stm.setString(3,telefon);
        stm.setString(4,email);
        stm.setString(5,permis);
        stm.setString(6, parola);
        //stm.setBinaryStream(7,new ByteArrayInputStream(photo),photo.length);
        stm.setBytes(7, photo);

        System.out.println(sql);
        stm.executeUpdate(sql);
        stm.close();
        c.commit();
    }
```

Comment: `setBytes()` is definitely supported in sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar. Are you *sure* you're getting the "java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver" message when you try to use `setBytes()`?

Comment: Yes, this is the exception :                                               java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.unused(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:466)
 at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:498)
 at Server.Database.addDriverData(Database.java:77)
 at Server.ServerConnection.register(ServerConnection.java:107)
 at Server.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:63)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: Okay, try using just `stm.executeUpdate()` instead of `stm.executeUpdate(sql)`. See if that works in conjunction with `setBytes()` in the parameter list.

Comment: It works with stm.executeUpdate() . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a `PreparedStatement` object has been created with

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement(sql);
```

the object has already processed the `sql` command text. When the time comes to execute the PreparedStatement all we need to do is

```java
stm.executeUpdate();
```

(The method call `executeUpdate(sql)` is intended to be used with `Statement` objects, not `PreparedStatement` objects.)