# Inserting Binary Array in SQLite DB with JDBC

Tags: java, arrays, sqlite, serialization, jdbc

I'm not terribly familiar with the serialization of objects in java but I'm trying to insert an object that I serialized into a table that consists of 2 columns: sampleTimestamp INTEGER, data BLOB. Using the code:

```
// Binary Serialization of the object
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                os.writeObject(result.getTopicInstance());
                byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
                os.close();

                String query = SQLiteInterface.getInstance().insertOI("data", "sampleTimestamp, data", "" + result.getTimestamp() + "," + byteArray);

public String insertOI(String tableName, String columnList, String values)
{
    return "INSERT OR IGNORE into " + tableName + "(" + columnList + ") values(" + values + ")";
}
```

The query returned from this is:

INSERT OR IGNORE into data(sampleTimestamp, data) values(1520448720940000000,[B@d32e4c)

The query indeed gets to SQLite and issued but returns the error:

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (unrecognized token: "[B@d32e4c)")
```

This is likely a sqlite formatting error because it doesn't like the "[" being in the query. *Edited based on comments below* - This is the .toString representation of the byte array. How do I correctly get the byte array into an insert statement for SQLite?

Comment: `B@` doesn't signify binary. `[B` signifies a one dimensional `byte[]` array. It's the default result of arrays' `toString()` and you don't want to save *that* in the database.

Comment: @Kayaman Added the code for the insertOI function. This is probably where it is getting casted.... Am I correct?

Comment: How would I insert it correctly?

Comment: Nothing's getting casted. You're converting it to a `String` at `"" + result.getTimestamp() + "," + byteArray`, but that won't work. Firstly because if you convert an array to a String like that, you just get something like `[B@d32e4c`, which has nothing to do with the contents of the array, and secondly because that's most certainly not the way to insert binary data. I recommend diving into the documentation to see how to insert binary data.

Comment: I see that it can be done this way with a PreparedStatement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180820/inserting-byte-array-into-blob-column but can it be done with a normal Statement?

Comment: There's basically no good reason ever to use a `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Considering I have an interface that can insert into any of 80 some tables and you cant use a "?" as part of a table name in an insert statement or a create statement... writing a generic INSERT INTO String a (String b, String c) values(String d, String e), is a lot easier to use. Better than having 80 + prepared statements for each one. Of course along with every type of query or create or delete that the app can generate.

Comment: Well that's just not true. You've gone for the lazy (and insecure) version and decided that "the less I write the better it is", but now you're also seeing a flaw in your design. In fact, if you had picked up an existing framework you would've needed to write even less, and you wouldn't be stuck with this problem.

Comment: Existing framework? You have a suggestion of something to look at?

Comment: There are dozens, depending on how you want to work with the db. JDBI for example. And they all use `PreparedStatements` internally.

Comment: Something I will have to look into and didn't know existed. Thanks.

Comment: You weren't the first person to think about creating something to make working with databases a bit easier.